# Generating variable in conanbuildinfo.cmake with the path to a folder in the conan package

Tags: cmake, conan

I am new to Conan and maybe this question is really simple but I'm struggling. My Conan binary package looks something like this:

```
binary_package
 ┣ include
 ┣ lib
 ┣ resources
 ┣ conaninfo.txt
 ┗ conanmanifest.txt
```

While calling `conan install` the conanbuildinfo.cmake is being generated and there are Cmake variables to include and lib folders being set with the path where these folders can be found.

There is no variable that specifically points to the resources folder. Is there a way that I can generate such a Cmake variable, for example in the Conan recipe?

**NOTE** I need the resources folder to be a separate folder, it contains additional config files that will be used in other parts of the project.

Comment: One recommendation. The ``cmake`` generator is considered legacy, and has already been removed in 2.0, which is planned before end of year. You should consider using the new tools from https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools.html. Also, starting with a template, like ``conan new hello/0.1 -m=cmake_lib`` can be very helpful to get started with these new tools.

Comment: You might be looking for ``self.cpp_info.resdirs`` for resources or ``self.cpp_info.builddirs`` for build scripts.